# What `git lfs migrate info` output means?

Tags: git, git-lfs

When I run `git lfs migrate info --everything` on a repository I get the following output:

```
... clipped
migrate: Examining commits:  99% (3622/3647)                                  migrate: Examining commits: 100% (3647/3647), done
*.json  56 MB     739/739 files(s)      100%
*.py    54 MB   2382/2382 files(s)      100%
*.ps1   9.4 MB    468/468 files(s)      100%
*.stl   5.3 MB        4/4 files(s)      100%
*.js    3.4 MB      45/45 files(s)      100%
```

1. What does the size mean? For example the `56 MB` for `*.json`
2. The `739` is probably the number of files, what what the first means and what the second means? (x/y - what is x, what is y?)
3. `100%` - percent of what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. The size is how many bytes the files in the repository with that extension that are not currently stored in LFS and match the criteria specified in the `info` command take up. Since your only criterion is `--everthing`, that's everything in your repo.
2. The first number is the number of matched files with that extension, while the second number is all the files in your selected commits with that extension. If you throw in the `--above=` restriction you can see the difference.
3. The percentage is just the ratio from the numbers in your second question.